# Yellowish residue from within water pipe

Tags: water, pipe, safety, valve

I was changing a valve today and used tissue to wipe water off the threads. While doing that, I also wiped the inside of the old pipe a bit through the opening, and I got yellow residue on the tissue (picture below). The old pipe seems to be brass/copper. I'm guessing it is caused by hard water and may be normal. But I am not sure. Can someone let me know whether you have seen the yellowish residue inside pipes before as well, and should I be concerned?

Btw, I get my water from the city.

Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: If water is on the hard side, would say it is normal.  Have hot water tank on a well system, should open drain every so often, to remove sediment, which can be yellow looking.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. But I am getting water from city. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Should be the same, caused by by hard water leaving probably calcium deposits in pipes.  In tanks it can build up enough that you can see it when opening drain at bottom and drain some water into a bucket.

Comment: Shouldn't calcium deposit be white instead of yellow?

Comment: I say calcium as generic mineral in water.  99.99 percent of cities/towns have to test their water all the time for any thing dangerous.  Pure calcium probably white, but in water would be mixed or can be another mineral mix.  Your city water department can give you the exact content of minerals in the water.